# how can I delete firebase data and also copy some high score data everyday

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Hi guys I'am learning android programming and I use firebase I would like to delete every day users data and who have high score I would like to copy his data another child
this is my database

```
project-12345
    /usersscore
        /user1   {   
            uid:user1
            timestamp:121121212
            score:125
}
        /user2{
            uid:user2
            timestamp:121121212
            score:50
              }
```

every day low score delete and high score  users data copy winner child `

```
project-12345
/winner
     /user1   {   
            uid:user1
            timestamp:121121212
            score:125
```

How can I do this sorry my bad English every tutorial for node.js is another language and I don't understand please help me Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase is a fairly reactive database as it has triggers for when data is created/updated/deleted, but does not have much for scheduled tasks and proactive actions.

You may want to look into some type of job like a scheduled CRON job to go in and manipulate the database as you want, I know GCP has support for this and Firebase and GCP communicate nicely. You could also set up a separate project with admin access based on auth rules with a button that does this, not automated but a solution.

Outside of doing that you could potentially query the data based on time stamps, and then for the winners segregate the data based on time stamps, figure out the highest score, and display it, after fetching all of it most likely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. First is to query the highest score then get the data and update your winner reference

```
DatabaseReference mDatabasePlayers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("usersscore");
Query mDatabaseHighestPlayer = mDatabasePlayers.orderByChild("score").limitToLast(1);
mDatabaseHighestPlayer.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            Player highScore = dataSnapshot.getValue(Player.class);

            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("winner").setValue(highScore);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't swallow errors
    }
});
```

Hope this helps

***Edit:*** To run daily in a specific time, you have to use scheduler. Heres an example using AlarmManager

```
alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

// Set the alarm to start at 6:30 PM
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 6);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

// setRepeating() lets you specify a precise custom interval--in this case,
// 1 day
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

Then do the above code on your broadcast receiver which is `AlarmReceiver` in my sample

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   //do function here
}
```

Comment: I would like every day automatically do this

Comment: this is good way but can we do this with node.js firebase function ?

Comment: Make your question clearer, you specified android there. You stated 
 _I'am learning android programming and I use firebase I would like to delete every day users data and who have high score I would like to copy his data_